# How can I make the product I`m clicking on to get deleted?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, frontend

I need some help with this product getting deleted, can`t quite figure this out.
[image]

I know what has to be done on the back-end, I need some help with Angular to make this button work only with the product it has been clicked on

Thanks

This is how I intend to delete it on the back end service :

```
async function deleteProduct(_id){
  return Product.findByIdAndDelete(_id)
}
```

Nothing on the controller yet :

```
productController.get(`/profile/delete`, async(req,res) => {

})
```

This is angular component :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IProduct } from 'src/app/interfaces/products';
import { IUser } from 'src/app/interfaces/user';
import { ProfileService } from './profile.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  user: IUser|undefined
  products: IProduct[] | any
  isEmpty : boolean = false
  constructor(private profileService: ProfileService){
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user = undefined
    this.products = undefined
    this.profileService.getUserDetails().subscribe({
      next: (user) => {
        this.user = user

        this.products = user.products

        if(this.products.length == 0){
          this.isEmpty = true
        }
        
      }
    })
  }
  deleteProduct(){}
  
}
```

As you can see most of it is empty, because I don`t have any ideas. I don`t want to load the page in detailed view or anything. I`d like to have this button working on this page

Comment: Can you share some code of your controller and view files?

Comment: Yes of course in a minute

Comment: When do you want it to be deleted (exactly)? After clicking on what for example?

Comment: Simply after clicking on the button, I want this product to get deleted from the client and the DB. I`ve managed to take the id like this :   <button (click)="deleteProduct(product?._id)">Delete</button>. I don`t know whether this helps though

Comment: Maybe an alert message would be nice UX just to confirm the action

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have in the template an ngFor (because on the image you have multiple products) and I assume `product` is an item of  the `products` array. If so, well, you are almost there. You have just to pass the `id` parameter to the `deleteProduct` method like this:

```
deleteProduct(id: number)
{
  // call the delete method
}
```

And don't forget to remove this product from the `products` array (or reload the array from the backend).